# What Keys Are Used in TLS 1.3?

Tags: tls, openssl, diffie-hellman

In TLS 1.2 the messages sent by client are encrypted under ClientWrite, and the messages send by server are encrypted under ServerWrite.

What about TLS 1.3? I don't see any Pre-Master-Secret being generated so what's the encryption and the decryption keys in this case?

Comment: [RFC 8446 - 7.3.  Traffic Key Calculation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-7.3)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry I didn't understand

Comment: @dan that link is to the actual technical design for TLS 1.3 keys.

Answer (score 2):

There are significant more keys generated in TLS 1.3 than there were in TLS 1.2. The [link](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-7.3) that [@Steffen Ullrich](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37315/steffen-ullrich) provided will show you the full formula in the TLS 1.3 RFC used to generate the various keys.

Beyond that link, I think the question you are asking is what are the equivalent keys in TLS 1.3 for what is the `ClientWrite` and `ServerWrite` keys in TLS 1.2- .

If that is the case, the answer is:

`client_application_traffic_secret_0` & `server_application_traffic_secret_0` -- but understand they aren't perfect correlations, since the fewer keys in TLS 1.2 are used in more places.